# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I see this error in xcode and I don't know what might be the cause. I'm not sure what I did to cause this problem:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L2'
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._vibrancyEffectView in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._blurEffectView in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._vibrancyEffect in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._doneAnimations in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._icons in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JVMenuPopoverViewController._image in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/JVMenuPopoverViewController.o
duplicate symbol _GMSOrientationMake in:
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/DesarrolloOS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aplication-cturpddkzvdycrbrfxglegcvaepl/Build/Intermediates/aplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MADViewController.o
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

```
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L2'
  ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
  linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 16 duplicate symbols.  These are values that have been included in both JVMenuPopoverViewController.o and MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o.  You need them to be only in one place.

Looking at the names, my guess is that you have put some or all of the implementation part into JVMenuPopoverViewController.h, and then imported that file in MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.m.  That way, both MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.o and JVMenuPopoverViewController.o end up with that implementation part and so it gets in your app twice.

You need to move the implementation pieces into JVMenuPopoverViewController.m.  Only the interface declarations should be in JVMenuPopoverViewController.h.

If you can't figure it out from there, or my guess is wrong, then you need to show the code for JVMenuPopoverViewController.h, JVMenuPopoverViewController.m, MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.h, MADVenuesTopListAroundViewController.m.